# intellisense in vcode only works when your files are on the top level folder. Is this a bug in vcode?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

When you have a folder on the top level, intellisense seems to stop working. For example, structure below won't work:

`-- Src
  -- code1.cs
  -- Code2.cs
  -- project.json
-- Tests
  -- UnitTest
       -- Test1.cs
  -- IntegrationTest
       -- Test2.cs`

But this will work:

```
Code1.cs
Code2.cs
project.json
-- Tests
     Test1.cs
-- IntegrationTest
     Test2.cs
```

Is this a limitation of vcode?

Comment: Posts consisting of nothing but images are not acceptable here. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The latest c# extension (v1.4) for visual studio code seems to have fixed this issue.